# Django interactive traceback using Werkzeug, `manage.py runserver_plus` Error

Tags: python, django, debugging, werkzeug

#### The Problem

I'm trying to run the interactive Werkzeug debugger included in Django with my Django project. After executing `python manage.py runserver_plus` from the command line to start the server with the debugger, I get the error:

```
Unknown command: 'runserver_plus'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I'm using `virtualenv`. Here is a look at what I have installed:

```
Django==1.5.2
Werkzeug==0.9.3
argparse==1.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

After looking at the [Django documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/django-extensions/runserver_plus.html#getting-started) and this question,

[How to use Werkzeug interactive traceback debugger in a Django project hosted on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069705/how-to-use-werkzeug-interactive-traceback-debugger-in-a-django-project-hosted-on)

even though I'm only trying to debug my project locally, everything should be working fine. I have Django installed, I have Werkzeug utils installed (even though I might not need to), and I am running the right command.

Any idea what could be going wrong? this should be a pretty straight forward action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to also install [django-werkzeug-debugger-runserver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-werkzeug-debugger-runserver) or [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions). And add whatever you install into `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, even after I've pip installed it and added it to my installed_APPs at the project level. should I add it to the app level as well?

Comment: running the regular python manage.py runserver gives me this error now: `ImportError: cannot import name AdminMediaHandler`

Comment: got it to work thanks to your answer. But I still have no idea how to get rid of the import error for the regular runserver or how installing this could have caused it. Thanks though!

Comment: link to question  for ImportError: cannot import name AdminMediaHandler: [Django manage.py runserver throws ImportError AdminMediaHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346433/django-manage-py-runserver-throws-importerror-adminmediahandler)

Comment: yep  INSTALLED APPS should include 'django_extensions'.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `django-extensions` is installed:

```bash
pip install django-extensions
```

And `django_extensions` is added to your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "django_extensions",
]
```