# Django manage.py runserver throws ImportError: AdminMediaHandler

Tags: python, django, werkzeug

### The Problem

When I run `python manage.py runserver` I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name AdminMediaHandler`.

ex.

```
(venv)agconti@agconti-Inspiron-5520:~/my_dev/github/stamped/stamped_project$ python manage.py runserver
ImportError: cannot import name AdminMediaHandler
```

This just started to happen after I installed the [django-werkzeug-debugger-runserver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-werkzeug-debugger-runserver).

Im using virtualenv. Here is what I have installed:

```
Django==1.5.2
Werkzeug==0.9.3
argparse==1.2.1
django-extensions==1.1.1
django-werkzeug-debugger-runserver==0.1.2
six==1.3.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I'm not sure what could be causing the conflict. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `django-werkzeug-debugger-runserver==0.1.2` is not compatible with Django1.5+, which I suspect you are using.

Try uninstalling it and remove it from `requirements.txt`. And use `django-extensions` instead, which you already have installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this. Then I forgot to activate virtualenv. Did you activate?